# Error while returning an inner class from a method (C++)

Tags: c++, class, templates, methods

This is my first post on the site so I apologise if I've made some sort of a mistake with something related to posting.

I am trying to return an object of an inner class through a method in the outer class and I keep getting random errors that do not seem to be connected to my method.

Before the main:

```
template <typename Type>
class Outer
{
public:
    class Inner
    {

    };
    Inner function();
};
```

After main:

```
template <typename Type>
Outer<Type>::Inner Outer<Type>::function()
{
    return Inner();
}
```

I have tried modifying the method a bit, but I still end up getting errors. Errors that I am getting with this version are visible [the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LCos.png).

Comment: Please include a [mcve] and the error message in the question.

Comment: can you add the main?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the function like

```
template <typename Type>
typename Outer<Type>::Inner Outer<Type>::function()
^^^^^^^^
{
    return Inner();
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Type>
class Outer
{
public:
    class Inner
    {

    };
    Inner function();
};



int main()
{
    auto obj = Outer<int>().function();
}

template <typename Type>
typename Outer<Type>::Inner Outer<Type>::function()
{
    return Inner();
}
```